# Python Repl in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am I right in assuming that the Python shell is coded in Python?  If so, where, might one find the source code?  If I wanted to write a shell program that did things differently, could I just copy the code to new_shell.py, make a few changes, and then set up a bash alias 'python'='python3 new_shell'?

Comment: "Am I right in assuming that the Python shell is coded in Python?" - nope.

Comment: Also that alias would break non-interactive use.

Comment: Check out the `code` module.

Answer (score 0):

There are various versions of Python. The most popular one is cpython, and the source code for that can be found here: [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython). If you want Python written in Python, check out [PyPy](https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy).